# HtmlAnchor.RenderControl throws a NullReference exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this piece of code right there

```
   var anchor = new HtmlAnchor {HRef = temp, InnerText = this.LinkDescription};
            anchor.Attributes.Add("class", "navActive back");
            anchor.ServerClick += new EventHandler(AnchorServerClick);
            writer.Write("<div id=\"leftnav\"><ul><li>");
            anchor.RenderControl(writer);
            writer.Write("</li></ul></div>");
```

inside a custom web control. I'm getting a nullReference exception at anchor.RenderControl, why? I debugged the above and the writer is not null, the anchor either. What's going on there? Thanks!

Edit: I'm adding the stack trace for debugging purpose

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor.GetPostBackOptions() +107
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor.RenderAttributes(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10975634
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer) +56
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +26
CER.Portal.Dashboard.Controls.BackLink.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +1151
```

Comment: is `temp` null? what line does it break?

Comment: temp is not null either, and it breaks at line anchor.RenderControl(writer);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code of the GetPostBackOptions method, you either need to set the Page property to the current page, or set the CausesValidation property to false:

```
private PostBackOptions GetPostBackOptions()
{
   PostBackOptions options = new PostBackOptions(this, string.Empty) 
   {
      RequiresJavaScriptProtocol = true
   };
   if (this.CausesValidation && (this.Page.GetValidators(this.ValidationGroup).Count > 0))
   {
      options.PerformValidation = true;
      options.ValidationGroup = this.ValidationGroup;
   }
   return options;
}
```

Either add *anchor.Page = this.Page* or *anchor.CausesValidation = false* before the RenderControl call.